# Why is Entity Framework generating unusual Guids?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have this very simple code using a very basic EF Core `DbContext`:

```
var eintrag = new CachingEintrag
{
    Name = whatever
};

await context.CachingEintrag.AddAsync(eintrag);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I have this very simple entity:

```
[Table("tbl_cache_eintrag")]
public partial class CachingEintrag
{
    [Key]
    [Column("guid", Order = 0)]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

In the DB I have this default Constraint:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_cache_eintrag_guid] DEFAULT (NEWID()) FOR [guid]
```

Normally when I add an entry to the table or any other table, no matter if I use `Guid.NewGuid()` in C# or `NEWID()` in SQL or just let the default constraint do the work, this results in a totally random new Guid as specified in Guid Version 4 specification.

But the above code results in this case in Guids like this:

```
6B347B1E-5DDD-414D-A611-08DB7428DC3C  
E08B85CB-9F16-4931-A612-08DB7428DC3C  
CB65491E-4EDA-435C-A613-08DB7428DC3C  
29748B11-ACAB-4077-A614-08DB7428DC3C  
4E9FA891-DF7F-43CD-A615-08DB7428DC3C  
6DF8379D-E785-421B-A616-08DB7428DC3C  
1A117B51-FC57-48D6-A617-08DB7428DC3C
```

Which have the version 4 version number are obviously not completely random.

My question is: how could that happen?

I tried to remove async stuff from the code but it didn't change.
I used SQL Server Profiler to see where the Guids come from. I noticed that the default constraint is not used but instead the Guids are inserted by the code.

I debugged to the point of `AddAsnyc()` to check if the Guid is set somehow before but that is not the case.

Comment: Looks like a sequential guid, which *if* your column is a `CLUSTERED` `PRIMARY KEY` is a better option, as it's always ascending. (Though, guid's are often frowned upon still as a C_PK candidate.)

Comment: The question is unclear. GUIDs aren't random to begin with. Pseudo-random GUIDs make terrible PKs, causing fragmentation. It's preferable to use sequential GUIDs.  [AddAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addasync?view=efcore-7.0) shouldn't be used either. That method is only meant for uncommon value generators like HiLo that need to eg retrieve a range of values from the database. Autogenerated IDs work just fine with `Add`. EF Core itself will retrieve the IDs of all inserted rows and update all objects with them

Comment: To avoid fragmentation, don't generate GUIDs on the client. Instead of `NEWID()` use `NEWSEQUENTIALID`()` as the default. GUIDs are still bad keys because of their size (compared to a 64-bit bigint) but at least you avoid inserting new lines in the middle of a 1M table

Comment: No one of you is really answering to my question here.

This querstion is not about wether or not GUIDs are good or Sequential Guids should be used or not. We use them in many thousands of Tables as a standard an are very happy with that. There is no way we will ever change that. 

Then question is, why are these Guids which I pasted above not completely randomly looking like any other guid i generated in the last 15 Years (And i work with that every day).

Guid V4 specification says that V4 guids should be created by using only random numbers. These Guids contain the V4 version number.

Comment: You're right no one has addressed the question of why a random guid does not appear to be random. As mentioned, the values look like `newsequentialid` except that they contain the 4 designator for random values. Perhaps to shed just a little more light on the matter you could confirm whether the final segment of the GUID matches one of the mac addresses on the host that generated it.

Comment: @Pflanzensindgut, the symptoms look like the EF [SequentialGuidValueGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.valuegeneration.sequentialguidvaluegenerator?view=efcore-7.0) somewhere in the code.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The final segment changes after I restart the hosted IIS process which creates the db entry so I think it can not be a MAC Adress.

Comment: Unless there are multiple mac addresses on the host in which case I believe it randomly picks one

Answer (score 0):

For GUID primary keys, the SQL Server provider automatically generates optimal sequential values, similar to SQL Server's NEWSEQUENTIALID function. Generating the value on the client is more efficient in some scenarios, i.e. an extra database round trip isn't needed to get the database-generated value, when a dependent is also being inserted that references that key.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/value-generation?tabs=data-annotations#guids

Comment: Are you certain from the code provided, that the GUID is being generated client side? Perhaps the OP could remove the database default to confirm this, in which case this would appear to be the correct answer

Comment: I can see in SQL Server Profiler that the Value is sent from the Client in the INSERT query.

Answer (score 0):

Something in your code base is generating the GUID. If you want to ensure that SQL Server is generating it, mark the PK as an Identity column:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Column("guid", Order = 0)]
public Guid Guid { get; set; }
```

You normally don't need to do this for PK columns when you follow EF's expected naming convention of "Id", "TableNameId", or "TableName_Id" but in your case since the class name is "CachingEintrag", it is expecting something like "CachingEintragId" so to use a different name as the PK, explicitly tell EF this is the Key and an Identity Column which will use the Default.

It's worth tracking down what code is generating that GUID because my guess is that it is trying to generate a Sequential-style GUID but it is not likely doing it correctly for how SQL Server clustered indexes would be optimized for. There are examples of generating sequential UUIDs but the ordering (HI/LO) importance depends on how the specific database engine stores and indexes the values, so that might have been taken from an example for another DBMS or some arbitrary attempt to make a value look more sort-able.